# Divergence energy tensor of Proca Lagrangian

Tags: electromagnetism, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Cosnider the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu\nu}-\frac{m^2}{2}A_\mu A^\mu$. Then  Euler Lagrange equations of motions are $\partial_\beta F^{\beta \alpha}-m^2 A^\alpha=0$. Then I computed the stress energy tensor 
$$
\Theta^{\mu \nu}=-\big[F^{\mu\lambda}F^{\nu}\,_\lambda-\frac{1}{4}\eta^{\mu \nu}F_{\lambda\rho}F^{\lambda\rho}+m^2(A^\mu A^\nu-\frac{1}{2}\eta^{\mu\nu}A_\lambda A^
\lambda)\big]
$$
I want to show $\partial_\mu\Theta^{\mu\nu}=0$, using the equations of motion and the Bianchi identities. Choosing a Lorenz gauge $\partial_\mu A^\mu=0$, then
$$
-\partial_\mu\Theta^{\mu\nu}=m^2A^\lambda F^{\nu}\,_{\lambda}+F^{\mu\lambda}\partial_\mu F^{\nu}\,_\lambda-\frac{1}{2}F_{\lambda\rho}\partial^\nu F^{\lambda\rho}+m^2A^\mu\partial_\mu A^\nu-m^2A^\lambda\partial^\nu A_{\lambda}=\frac{1}{2}F_{\rho\lambda}(2\partial^\rho F^{\nu\lambda}-\partial^\nu F^{\rho\lambda})
$$
Now, I want to use a Bianchi identity to conclude that this is zero, but I get stuck. Any thoughts for the next step?